# Opening Ports in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, server, ssh, 22.04, iptables

I understand that this may seem simple enough and there are many tutorials out there, but I've tried almost everything. My goal is to open any port on my Ubuntu desktop (starting with 22 for ssh) and have access remotely.

- I have installed Open-SSH server / client and checked for processes running.
- Connected to my desktop with ssh from my laptop through LAN (ssh works)
- Talked with ISP provider technician to disable my connection's firewall.
- DDNS enabled and Port Forwarded on my router.
- Checked if Double NAT with `traceroute youtube.com`
- Checked for open port with https://portchecker.co/ on wired connection (Closed)
- Re-checked after removing wired connection, through smartphone's hotspot. (Closed)
- Checked / allowed rules in other stuff like `ufw` and `iptables`.
- Tried checking ports on my fresh Ubuntu installation laptop.
- My router has a firewall but does not offer the ability to disable it (not that it matters really, since I've tried with phone's data)

Looks like nothing is wrong but the ports still remain externally closed. I'm open to suggestions.